# Rotating particles in two different axis

Tags: modeling, mesh, particles, vertices

I'm having some trouble randomizing these particles on top of my cylinder. My goal is to randomize the orientation of my particles with respect to the object's y-axis, which makes the particles stand up as shown in the image below, however now I am having some issues randomizing their phase in the z-axis. Hence they all look like they have a uniform rotation about the z-axis. Anyone have any ideas how I might be able to stand my particles up while also randomizing their phase in the z-axis? The origin of all my particles is located in the middle of their base at the bottom. I also tried creating duplicates and rotating them myself, but this didn't work out either. Please help! :(
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a setup for having the objects rotate only on 1 axis:

[image]

Comment: Hey Sanbaldo, thanks for the reply! I've been able to get it to randomize the phase about 1 axis, however I'm still having issues getting it to rotate about the z-axis. :( The best idea I was able to come up with was to make multiple objects with different z-axis rotations, then enable "Object Rotation", but I'm not sure if that would be the optimal solution.